# PropertyChangedEventManager will call a function but NOT a lambda. Why?

Tags: c#, .net-core, weak-events, weakeventmanager

In my C# app (.NET 6) One of my class' constructors hooks up to a `PropertyChanged` notification of one of the arguments passed in.  I did it like this:

```
public ProfileSource(ISystemService sys, Routine routine, Aspect aspect)
    : base(sys)
{
    Routine = routine;
    Aspect = aspect;

    PropertyChangedEventManager.AddHandler(
        Routine,
        (_, _) =>
        {
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Profiles));
        },
        nameof(IRoutine.AreResultsValid));
}
```

In Debug mode I was was surprised to find my lambda was not being called when the `Routine` object raises that property changed for its `AreResultsValid` property.

But when I changed that lambda to instead be a *member function* of the class, suddenly it started working.

```
public ProfileSource(ISystemService sys, Routine routine, Aspect aspect)
    : base(sys)
{
    Routine = routine;
    Aspect = aspect;

    PropertyChangedEventManager.AddHandler(
        Routine,
        OnResultsValidChanged,
        nameof(IRoutine.AreResultsValid));
}

private void OnResultsValidChanged(object? sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Profiles));
}
```

With this change (and no other), my handler is called every time.

I can switch back and forth and observe the effect.  Lambda version: handler not called.  Function version: handler called

Can someone tell me why this would be?  What am I missing here?

(Edited to add: I use the lambda approach in several other places and it's always worked.  Now I'm starting to worry that i need to go and change those all to be functions, just in case)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62621885/17034

Comment: Hans, thanks (yet again) for answering me.  Would this issue also raise its head with a private, local function?  Because I just realized I encountered exactly the same problem when was using local functions for this purpose a while back.  I even asked a question about it.  I had completely forgotten but it must have a vague memory of that which made me try the member function..  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71668976/why-does-a-local-function-not-work-with-propertychangedeventmanager

Comment: The member function forces `this` to be captured.  I can't see what kind of object it refers to.  If it is eligible to be garbage collected then the handler stops being called.